# Join new table with old, update non matching ids

Tags: mysql, join, min

I have one main table (t1)

```
id           value     group
------------------------------
5            22        1 
6            55        1 
7            18        2 
8            11        2
```

And a cache table (t2)

```
id           value     group
------------------------------
1            12        1
2            30        1
3            18        2
4            11        2
```

The main table auto-increments, so everytime data is saved, the table is cleared and new ids are created, going up each time.

I need to update t2.id with t1.id so they are matching.

Required result for cache table(t2):

```
id           value     group
------------------------------
5            12        1
6            30        1
7            18        2
8            11        2
```

**Attempt1:**

```
UPDATE t1, t2 SET t1.id=t2.id WHERE t1.id < t2.id ORDER BY id ASC
```

**Attempt2:**

```
UPDATE t1, t2 SET t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.id IS < MIN(t2.id) ORDER BY t1.id ASC
```

**Attempt3:**

```
  UPDATE t1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      MIN(t1.id) AS ID
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY ID) m ON t1.ID = m.ID
  INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: does it mean (*table is cleared and new ids are created*) ID's also are reset back to 1?. if **NO**, how can `cache` table be possibly joined with `main` table?

Comment: If it's a *cache* table, why aren't you writing the ID of the main table to it?

Comment: that requirement won't achieve a good result IMO

Comment: you might want to add a true id to both tables instead of the column that is called an id but isn't one

Comment: @Robert & Wolfgang - the main table is cleared each time data is saved, so unfortunately I can't write a matching/true ID to it.@John -  that could be a future solution to reset the ids to 1, but for the moment, due to other conflicts, the ids do not reset.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt, try and let me know:

```
  Update cache t2
  set t2.id = t2.id + 
    (select min(t1.id)-min(t2.id) from main t1, cache t2);
```

**EDIT:**

If you could do two step query, its much easier.

```
 DECLARE diffValue INTEGER;
 SELECT min(t1.id)-min(t2.id) into diffValue from main t1, cache t2;
 UPDATE cache t2 set t2.id = t2.id + diffValue;
```

Comment: thanks Yogendra, I had an error with the "FROM main t1, cache t2" part. However based on your attempt, this almost worked! But duplicates the value of the first row -  `Update cache t2, main t1
  set t2.id = t2.id + 
    (select min(t1.id)-min(t2.id))` gives me 5,5,5,5 in t2.id column instead of 5,6,7,8

Comment: @miles_holt: You mentioned you made some adjustment in the query. What was the final query which resulted into `5,5,5,5`?

Comment: please see above comment, I removed "from main t1, cache t2" and placed it in "update cache t2, main t1"

Comment: @miles_holt: That changes the meaning of what I was thinking. Can you use two step query?

Comment: i think that could work but im just getting syntax error when declaring diffvalue, i tried using begin and end labels but no luck

Comment: @miles_holt I missed the type in declaration. Updated the query. please check.

Comment: thanks, gave it a try but it's still saying there's a syntax error near "DECLARE diffValue INTEGER"

Comment: @miles_holt Are you writing this code in some procedure or stand alone query?

Comment: I'm trying it in mysql query first

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18692/discussion-between-yogendra-singh-and-miles-holt)

Comment: @miles_holt : Can you please try `DECLARE diffValue INT;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use joins in update syntax.

Firstly delete all records in the table:

```
DELETE * FROM t2;
```

Then write the new data in it:

```
INSERT INTO t2
(t2.id, t2.value, t2.group)
SELECT t1.id, t1.value, t1.group FROM t1
```

Is this what u wanted?

Comment: thanks n00b, the issue with that is I want to keep the values in cache, and not clear the whole table. This is so I can compare the values between main and cache, based on id. So I'm looking to just join the min(t1.id) with min(t2.id) where t1.group=t2.group and update all rows ascending in t2.

Comment: are there always only 4 entries?

Comment: no that's an example, there are many groups and the content will be user-defined